# Handling multiple update request at the same time

Tags: api, spring-boot, request

I got some new case for me so there is an item A in database that has a quantity 1 and we got 2 user that want to checkout 1 Item A at the same time. How should the API response for these type of multiple request should we handling one of them and what is the approach for handling multiple request like this ?? I'm using springboot and sql server.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL server

Comment: i think we can use database locking in here